# Windows 10 Assigned Access: lost focus after boot or unlock

Tags: uwp, windows-10, focus, kiosk

I made an application with UWP (Universal Windows Platform) working in Kiosk mode (Assigned Access in Pro+ version). It listens USB HID (ID-card tagging) device's input with KeyDown+KeyPress event. It worked very well while focused itself. (If you don't have HID device, you can simulate it with just keyboard typing...)

But after boot/reboot or unlock from screensaver, it resumed from freezing state but lost focus (maybe) and no events fired when HID input. It always needs to click (or touch) on app's screen to be worked.

I tried it in normal mode (not in Assigned Access) then it worked perfectly as designed both on reboot and unlock, it only did not work in Assigned Access mode. All types of Focus() or SetForgroundWindow(), etc. methods did not work.

Anyone knows what is the problem and what can I do?

Comment: Have you tried restoring focus to the field by attaching event handler to the  `Resuming` or `LeavingBackground` event in App.xaml.cs? Is such even executed when screen saver is unlocked?

Comment: Most RFID scanners and other devices that emulate an HID device offer an alternative serial communication mode which dramatically simplifies reading in code. What's the manufacturer/model of the scanner?